# Dismiss UIView within ViewController by tapping outside of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touchesbegan

I'm presenting a UIView over my ViewController which contains a table view that covers the whole view controller. I want to dismiss the UIView when tapping outside of the UIView, but have not found anything that helps the cause. This is what I'm trying to do, and it should work but it's not registering touches even if the UIView is not presented. Anyone dealt with a similar issue?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: UITouch? = touches.first

        if touch?.view != fullSessionView {
            fullSessionView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Minor criticism? If I may? You *present* a `UIView`. This view is *usually* part of a `UIViewController`. (Think MVC.) It's *literally* impossible to present a "table view that covers the whole view controller". This sort of description happens all the time. In your case? It may be important... the sooner you understand the difference between a view and it's controller, the easier it will be for you to understand where tapping is processed by the OS.

Comment: if the view covers the whole screen then add a button on navigation bar to dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize UITapGestureRecognizer with a target and action to your view to be added, like so:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
Then, you should implement the handler, which will be called each time when a tap event occurs:
@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    self.removefromSuperview() // this will remove added view from parent view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd try to see if any of the built-in [presentation styles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) could work for you. But you'd have to embed your view in a view controller.

If you want to stick with a `UIView` you could try presenting your `UIView` on top of a transparent background `UIView` that covers the whole screen and attaching a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the transparent background.

Tapping the background would trigger a call back (via delegate, closure, etc) that would then remove your view.

Answer (score 0):

You should always call `super`, like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event) /// always call the super
```

But anyway, you want to see if `fullSessionView` contains the touch. So instead of checking the view where the touch happened, you probably want to check the *location* of where the touch happened. Something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    let touch = touches.first
    guard let location = touch?.location(in: fullSessionView) else { return }
    if !fullSessionView.frame.contains(location) {

         /// tapped outside fullSessionView
         fullSessionView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: You generally don't want views removing themselves from their parent views. `UIView`'s responsibility is to "manage" (i.e. add, resize, remove) all of its subview. So instead of intercepting touches to make the view remove itself, the trigger should call back to its parent view and remove the view in question.

Comment: @PietroRea are you sure? As far as I know that only way to remove a subview is to call `removeFromSuperview` from itself...

Comment: Oh I meant where `removeFromSuperview` is called...I think I misread your code. It does look like the parent is removing the child. Whoops